# Magento 2 How to get multiple table rates data programmatically?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I want to display a custom notice on cart page "if customer's order total above $299, then he is qualified for free shipping". For that I have imported following table rates:

**Country | Region/State |  Zip/Postal Code |   Order Subtotal (and above) |    Shipping Price**

US |    * | * | 0 | 15

US |    * | * | 299 | 0

I can get single table rate using `collectRatesByAddress()` function of `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping` class, but I can't get multiple table rates. Please see sample code as follows:

```
$quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCountryId("US") 
            ->setCity("New York") 
            ->setPostcode("11209") 
            ->setRegionId("") 
            ->setRegion("") 
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates(); 

$shippingCarrier = 'tablerate';
$carriers[$shippingCarrier] = '';

$result = $this->_shippingModel->collectRatesByAddress($shippingAddress, array_keys($carriers))->getResult();

foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $rate) {
    echo $rate->getPrice();
}
```

Please give me any solution/suggestion/hint to resolve this problem.

Thanks in appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the method `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectRates` ?

Or, Alternatively you may query the database table `shipping_tablerate` which has the table rates stored in it.

Comment: After investigation, I found that collectRatesByAddress() returns applicable table rate data based on subtotal. So finally I used suggested alternate solution. @nikin Thank you for the guide lines.